# Automate mirroring GitHub to GCP Source Repository?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, google-cloud-source-repos

We run Google **Cloud Functions** (python), which require to be deployed from Google Cloud **Source Repository**. Since all the code is stored on GitHub we resort to first **mirroring GitHub** into Source Repository. Although this only requires a few mouse clicks, it becomes a burden to repeat over 3+ projects (dev, staging, production) times 5+ repos (5+ apps).

I am looking to automate the mirroring config, preferably to add into the Terraform automation we already use, into a hands-off project configuration. Does the Google API support this mirroring automation? So far on my Google Cloud expedition *everything* was available in their API!

I fail to find Terraform examples though, and would appreciate a tip.

Come to think of it, if I can take Source Repository out of the equation, that would be just fine with me too. After all, I only use it as a pass-through / empty shell.

Comment: Have you read https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo? You can mirror your GitHub repo into a Google Cloud Source Repository to simplify this.

Comment: it's the mirroring that I want to automate actually. I improved the question with the correct terminology - thanks @ydaetskcoR

Comment: Did you try with a `deployKeyId` value?

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Source Repository API includes a Repo resource that has a [Mirror Config](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos#mirrorconfig) object where you could type in your Github's URL, webhook and credentials to automate this procedure. I would initially test it with the [create method](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos/create), but if you have an existing Cloud Source Repository I believe the [patch method](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos/patch) will also be worth exploring.

Additionally, there is an [open Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/142550612) in order to connect a repository via the Cloud Build GitHub App that I recommend you to star and follow, as it could further ease your automation needs.

Answer (score 0):

Mirror Object is read only, hence cannot be used in create/update methods.

I'm facing the same problem and it seems like the only way would be from the ui or automate it as a pull-push job of some sort.